# Installing ROS fuerte on Fedora 17

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am installing ROS fuerte in fedora 17 following the installation guide at http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Fedora

I have no problem until step 1.4, when I run rosdep install -a I get the following errors:

> ERROR: the following packages/stacks
> could not have their rosdep keys
> resolved to system dependencies:
> roslaunch: No definition of
> [python-yaml] for OS version [17]

> python_qt_binding: No definition of [ros] for OS [fedora]

> simmechanics_to_urdf: No definition of [python-yaml] for OS version [17]

> rviz: No definition of [ros] for OS
> [fedora] rosparam: No definition of
> [python-yaml] for OS version [17]
> librviz_tutorial: No definition of [ros] for OS [fedora]
> rviz_plugin_tutorials: No definition of [ros] for OS [fedora]

I have also add the yaml file on ticket #3929 with no luck.

System information: Fedora 17 64bits

Thank you very much. Regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52997/installing-ros-fuerte-on-fedora-17/) by [jplata](https://answers.ros.org/users/4014/jplata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fedora support is experimental.  You will probably need to [contribute definitions[(http://ros.org/doc/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html) before rosdep will work for your packages.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not using Fedora, so I am guessing blindly.

Make sure you have the latest version of rosdep installed (I think that's 0.10.12) and run

```
rosdep update
```

Hopefully that solves the error with python-yaml.

Then call:

```
rosdep install -ai
```

hopefully that resolves problem with "No definition of [ros]"

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1